# Spring Data flow server - RDBMS

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We developing a service and the target datastore for my service is Cassandra. I want to use spring data flow for ingesting feed. As data flow server requires RDBMS to keep track of workflow, i am forced to choose an RDBMS (eg:postgres) and need to provision it for SDFS. My question is that should DB(used by SDFS) be highly available & scalable to keep my service up/running on target runtime(eg: kubernetes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataflow usage of DB is very light. It does not mean you should not provide a high available DB in production though. As far as it concerns to scaling concerns it's very light on accessing the DB so you don't need to worry about it being a burden on it. It only uses db to store metadata not during the ingestion of data over the streams

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong .By reading,"It only uses db to store metadata not during the ingestion of data over the streams", I understand that the streams will be working fine even the DB is down. We will definitely make it highly available, just curious how tolerant it is if DB is down for a while.

Comment: If the DB is down, streams will continue to work, the server itself will not work properly since it needs to load the definitions, registered apps from the database, but deployed streams have no dependency on scdf db